# 9-path drawable background : Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 30
```

and a 9-path: msg_bg
[image]

```
       23 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       24 android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
       25 android:layout_width="match_parent"
       26 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       27 android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
       28 android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
       29 android:background="@drawable/msg_bg"
       30 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       31 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       32 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

work fine in android > 5 but in android < 5 error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
```

Comment: can you post this background graphic? maybe it is somehow malformed...

Comment: can you post your xml file? what is XML file line #23?